# Passport verification

Tags: passports, canada

My passport is valid through 2021.  The last name on my passport is my divorced name. My divorce decree states my name change. Is my divorce decree sufficient to prove my present last name along with my passport of divorced last name?

Comment: Usually, yes, but different countries might look at it differently.  Where are you planning to travel?

Comment: How much does it cost to renew a Canadian passport? Methinks that $!60 is worth the peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether your tickets and visa are in your married name or liberated name.

If the tickets and passport match with the same name (even it's your old name), then there’s really no concern. However, if there is a discrepancy between the tickets and the passport then the [Canadian government themselves note](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/change-name.html) that you might have a problem:

> Be sure that you make all of your travel bookings, such as tickets and hotels, in the name that appears on your new passport.
>
> **If the name on the passport or travel document doesn't match your bookings, you could have issues such as:
>   countries not letting you in [and]
>   travel companies not letting you board**
>
> This could happen even if you carry your marriage or civil partnership certificate with you.
>   Check with the consulate of the country you plan to visit or transit through, or your travel agent about your name change.

If tickets are in your liberated name but your passport is in your married name, you may want to get your passport updated ASAP. You may have trouble boarding as the airline might be the one that’s giving you a hassle. I’d phone them and ask them what they recommend.

You may want to get at least one form of photo ID in your new name.

Most countries allow for emergency / expedited passport issuance or for name changes even on unexpired passports. It's unclear if you're traveling to Canada or are Canadian yourselves, but [Canada's policies about passport re-issuance for name changes](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/change-name.html) are pretty standard so you can look at them as a reference.